# prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" will not work for not referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I load my modules in the bootstrapper with:

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var moduleCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog();
        moduleCatalog.ModulePath = @".\Modules";
        return moduleCatalog;
    }
```

which works fine when the project of the modules are referenced in the shell project. The correct ViewModels will be injected by the following attached property.

`<UserControl prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" [..]</>`

Unless I remove the project reference the ViewModels will not be set anymore by the prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True".

Does anybody know the what causes that? You can watch this behaviour on the project https://github.com/mfe-/Get.the.solution.Prism.Demo . How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, when the ViewModelLocationProvider calls the `_defaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver`, the call to Type.GetType(string) returns null.

This might be related to how MEF loads assemblies in general.  This seems to be a common probem with MEF and a Google search will return a lot of results with similar issues.
Here is someone with the same problem:

[Type.GetType returns null when using MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138163/type-gettype-returns-null-when-using-mef)

You could try adding the plugin location in the probing path of the application.

I personally never use MEF as a DI container, because it's not one.  But that is a conversation for another day.

**EDIT:**
Actually, I just thought of a better way to get around this.  Simply override ConfigureViewModelLocator in your bootstrapper like this:

```
        protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

        ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(viewType =>
        {
            var viewName = viewType.FullName;
            viewName = viewName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
            var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
            var suffix = viewName.EndsWith("View") ? "Model" : "ViewModel";
            var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", viewName, suffix);

            var assembly = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var type = assembly.GetType(viewModelName, true);

            return type;
        });
    }
```

This way we can ask the assembly for the type directly and not try to have the framework figure it out for us.

Comment: +1, add type existence check `if (assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.FullName == viewModelName).Count() > 0)` before line `var type = assembly.GetType(viewModelName, true);` because its not necessary to have ViewModel for every View.