# MVVM Attached Property View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

I've got this problem with Attached Properties in MVVM. I'm building a C# WPF application.

I'm filling a ObserverableCollection with custom Classes of the type ClassObject. And from this collection I'm creating ClassShapeViews on a canvas. These ClassShapeViews need a reference to the ClassObject to show correct information.

To pass the ClassObject reference i'm binding to a AttachedProperty in the XAML like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ClassObjectList}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas  x:Name="canvas" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" 
                    DragEnter="canvas_DragEnter" 
                    DragOver="canvas_DragOver" 
                    Drop="canvas_Drop"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- This part doesn't work-->
                <shape:ClassShapeView>
                    <Style TargetType="shape:ClassShapeView">
                        <Setter Property="shape:ClassShapeView.ClassObject" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    </Style>
                </shape:ClassShapeView>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

In the Code behind of the ClassShapeView I'm handeling the DependencyProperty:

```
public partial class ClassShapeView : UserControl
{
    protected ClassShapeViewModel viewModel { get { return DataContext as ClassShapeViewModel; } }
    public ClassShapeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ClassShapeViewModel();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClassObjectProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ClassObject", typeof(ClassObject), typeof(ClassShapeView), new PropertyMetadata(default(ClassObject)));

    public static void SetClassObject(UIElement element, ClassObject value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ClassObjectProperty, value);
    }

    public static ClassObject GetClassObject(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ClassObject)element.GetValue(ClassObjectProperty);
    }

    public ClassObject MyClassObject
    {
        get { return viewModel.ClassObject; }
        set { viewModel.ClassObject = value; }
    }

}
```

After receiving the ClassObject Reference I want to send this reference to the attached ViewModel with the property MyClassObject. The data in the ClassShapeView is bound to the ViewModel.

I just can't figure out how to to transform the ClassObject Reference form the CodeBehind to the ViewModel.

Comment: The DataContext of an item container (and all its children) is already automatically set to the appropriate data item object. So setting `ClassObject` to `{Binding}` seems entirely redundant. Just remove `this.DataContext = new ClassShapeViewModel();` from your ClassShapeView's constructor to enable inheriting the DataContext and let the UserControl directly operate on the ClassObject instance in the inherited DataContext.

Comment: This is a very unusual way to do things. Ordinarily, relationships and connections between the view models are set up by the view models themselves. The view merely reflects what it finds there. Why not bind properties of ClassObject to properties of ShapeView? At any rate, in your DataTemplate, `{Binding}` is the DataContext -- the ClassObject. You want `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. I'd try that on the ShapeView directly, not in a style setter.

Comment: In other words, there is no need that the UserControl uses its own view model. Especially it should never create its own view model instance when it is used in a scenario where it should operate on an inherited DataContext. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37475541/1136211).

Comment: @Clemens So you are saying that a usercontrol can't have it's own ViewModel?

Comment: So the new question is? Do i use a viewmodel or not and how do I set the object reference so it can be bound to in the usercontrol?

Comment: As already said, when a UserControl is used in an ItemTemplate, it gets the appropriate data item object by inheriting the DataContext from its parent control (i.e. the item container). Explicitly setting the DataContext overwrites this behaviour and gets you into the trouble you have right now. So as a general rule, *never* set the DataContext of a UserControl explicitly.

Comment: @Clemens I don't understand what you mean. how do i set the "data item object"? How does my code know what reference the ClassObject has?

Comment: You haven't looked at the other answer I've linked. Anyway, when the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property is bound to a collection of `ClassObject` instances (as what I suppose is your ClassObjectList), then the DataContext of each item container (e.g. a ContentPresenter) is set to the respective element from the collection. This DataContext is inherited into the ItemTemplate, so that the controls inside the DataTemplate (e.g. your UserControl) already get the correct `ClassObject` element as their DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens Now Understand it. And it works. You are my hero!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Clemens i have the answer

"when the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property is bound to a collection of ClassObject instances (as what I suppose is your ClassObjectList), then the DataContext of each item container (e.g. a ContentPresenter) is set to the respective element from the collection. This DataContext is inherited into the ItemTemplate, so that the controls inside the DataTemplate (e.g. your UserControl) already get the correct ClassObject element as their DataContext."

So my XAML looks like this now

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ClassObjectList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas  x:Name="canvas" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" 
                         DragEnter="canvas_DragEnter" 
                         DragOver="canvas_DragOver" 
                         Drop="canvas_Drop"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <shape:ClassShapeView/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And my View looks like this:

```
    public partial class ClassShapeView : UserControl
{
    public ClassShapeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
    }
}
```